# How to make a switch that skips switch?

Tags: java, switch-statement, case

NOTE: its only a basic java program no jframe etc.

```
import java.io.*;
public class Case1 {
public static void main(String[] Ropher) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    int t; int y;

    System.out.print("Welcome To M.Y Hotel!");

    System.out.println("\nPlease Select For Information");

    System.out.println("1 --- Bed Menu");
    System.out.println("2 --- Food Menu");
    System.out.println("3 --- Exit");

    System.out.println("");
    t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    switch (t){

    case 1 :
        System.out.println("1 --- Single Bed");
        System.out.println("2 --- Double Bed");
        System.out.println("3 --- Family Bed");
        System.out.println("4 --- Social Bed");
    break;

    case 2:
        System.out.println("1 --- Appetizer");
        System.out.println("2 --- Soup");
        System.out.println("3 --- Breakfast");
        System.out.println("4 --- Lunch");
        System.out.println("5 --- Dinner");
    break;

    }

    System.out.println("Please Select");
    y = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    switch (y){

    case 1:
        System.out.println("Single Beds: ");
        System.out.println("Standard --- P750");
        System.out.println("King Bed --- P1000");
        System.out.println("Crystal Bed --- P1750");
        System.out.println("Water Bed --- P2000");

    case 2:
        System.out.println("Double Beds: ");
        System.out.println("Deluxe A --- P1000");
        System.out.println("Deluxe B --- P1500");
        System.out.println("Water Double Bed --- P3000");




    }
}

}
```

i want to make a program that will skip a case if i choose the case 2 in switch (t), something will pop-up for (e.g Appetizer) the information for that selection and skip the cases in switch (y).

Comment: Why can't you just put your `switch(y)` inside the `case 1` statements . Or you may add a `return` somewhere. There are plenty of solutions here

Comment: `if (t != 2) switch (y)`

Comment: You should really use a design pattern though.

Comment: i dont know how to put 'return' .
can you make me some examples? @SylvainBiehler

Comment: I don't know about "a design pattern" but it definitely feels like each of these should be in a separate method...

Comment: if your referring to flow chart, i cant make them its hard for me to make them sorry T_T @KevinKal

Comment: Check the answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640269/hierarchical-menu-in-view-based-on-parent-child-class

Comment: @GeoddieChristopherOrtiz You might look at the state machine design pattern, based on Kevin's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int t = 0;
    int y;
    welcome(t, br);
    System.out.println("Please Select");
    y = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    switch (y) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Single Beds: ");
        System.out.println("Standard --- P750");
        System.out.println("King Bed --- P1000");
        System.out.println("Crystal Bed --- P1750");
        System.out.println("Water Bed --- P2000");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Double Beds: ");
        System.out.println("Deluxe A --- P1000");
        System.out.println("Deluxe B --- P1500");
        System.out.println("Water Double Bed --- P3000");
        break;
    }
}

private static void welcome(int t, BufferedReader br) throws Exception {
    System.out.print("Welcome To M.Y Hotel!");
    System.out.println("\nPlease Select For Information");
    System.out.println("1 --- Bed Menu");
    System.out.println("2 --- Food Menu");
    System.out.println("3 --- Exit");
    System.out.println("");
    t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    switch (t) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("1 --- Single Bed");
        System.out.println("2 --- Double Bed");
        System.out.println("3 --- Family Bed");
        System.out.println("4 --- Social Bed");
        break;
    case 2:
        welcome(t, br);
        break;
    }
}
```